# unable to set mysqld --max_allowed_packet=16M in opencms installation

Tags: java, mysql, opencms

i am installing opencms first time ,. I found a problem during installtion[image: error of my sql max allow packet variable]

i have tried SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216; and  max_allowed_packet=32M ; as per openCms installtion guide, but didnt help.

any idea or help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: finally i found the solution ,
i was not opening the notepad with admin rights , thanks for all support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in the my.ini file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

and restart mysql server

Comment: Tamil's answer is correct. But Devesh, also tell us what operating system you're on. Note that the config file name differs between OS, sometimes it's my.ini, sometimes it's my.cnf, and also - where is your my.ini located? In which folder?

Comment: i am using windows 7 , and config file name is my.ini under mysql folder